# styles.xml not aplying as intended

Tags: android, xml, background, statusbar, android-theme

So, I've been working on an app and changed the styles.xml so it has custom colorPrimaryDark, colorPrimary and colorAccent. In some activities I've also added the `android:background="@color/some_color"` to their main layout so it overrides the default one.

The thing is that is being applied in the preview window but when I run it on my phone that doesn't happen, the colors stay the same instead of changing to the ones I'm telling it to.

What am I doing wrong?

Here are some parts from my styles.xml and a random activity:

styles.xml:

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/montserrat</item>
</style>
```

activity:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
```

Answer (score 0):

you just change

> @color/colorPrimaryDark

with

> ?attr/colorPrimaryDark

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark">
```

you can try this for api >= 21

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark));
}
```

Comment: Well, I'm sorry but that didn't work. And it doesn't help me with the status bar. But thanks anyway! ;)

Comment: if you want change color statusbar maybe you can try this in your style <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/color_primary</item>

Comment: I've tried that already and it doesn't work...but the thing is, in preview the app has the right colors, but when I run it on my phone it doesn't....

Comment: you can try condition in your activity like my post